# What makes a WP7 app unique

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one app, I copied the whole folder and proceeded to edit it out, turning it into a new app.

Now, during testing, if I debug the first app (let's call it parent app), and then proceed to debug the second app (child app), the parent app is no longer there. It has been replaced by the child app and vice versa.

Digging deeper into this, I proceed to change out some of the Properties. I changed the Assembly Information to fit it properly, changed the GUID and all.

The only piece of data that stays the same is the Assembly name. The Assembly name is the same for both of the apps because changing it is a bit trickier since I get an debugger error if I do that.

My question is what makes an app unique and how could I achieve to have both the apps installed at the same time ?

Comment: What does you WPManifest.xml file look like for both of them?

Comment: You're right, I looked at the WPManifest.xml file and found that the ProductID="{XXXXXX}" was the same for both. I created a new app and copied it's ProductID to one of the ones mentioned and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, an app is considered unique based on the 
ProductID="{XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}" line found in the WPManifest.xml.

This line can't be found in the Properties, and can only be found in the mentioned xml.